# Amazon s3 prevent opening media url in browser

Tags: amazon-s3

We are using Amazon s3 for managing images and videos. We are able integrate it successfully and videos and images loading fine in our website.

eg urls
https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/prod/image/20160810065109.png
https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/prod/video/43443.mp4

We would like to restrict users from taking the above links directly in browser to download or play. I understand we can allow few IPs to access the amazon s3 urls. We have andriod app, fetching these amazon s3 urls. So IP restriction won't work. Is amazon s3 provides any other mechanisms for this restriction and allow?Please advise. It would be great if we have an example of its implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most suitable solution would be to use an [Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).

**By default, all objects in Amazon S3 are private.** You can then add permissions so that people can access your objects. This can be done via:

- Access Control List permissions on individual objects
- A Bucket Policy (that grants wide-ranging access based on path, IP address, referrer, etc)
- IAM Users and Groups (that grant permissions to Users with AWS credentials)
- Pre-Signed URLs

A **[Pre-Signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)** can be used to grant access to S3 objects as a way of "overriding" access controls. A normally private object can be accessed via a URL by appending an expiry time and signature. This is a great way to serve private content without requiring a web server.

If your goal is to serve content only where a Pre-Signed URL is used, then:

- Do not assign any permissions via the normal methods listed above (this keeps them private by default)
- Use Pre-Signed URLs to access objects

This way, the only way to access an object will be to use a Pre-signed URL (which has a signature). No bucket policy is required.

It would be the **responsibility of your application** to appropriately **authenticate** users to determine whether they are allowed access to objects in S3. If they are granted access, then your application should **generate pre-signed URLs as authenticated links** to the objects. These URLs will only be valid for a **limited time duration**.

This is best done by having a **back-end app** (probably running on Amazon EC2 or AWS Lambda) perform the authentication and then generate the URLs. Your Android app could then use the URLs to access the content in S3.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for detailed reply. Let me take look.

Comment: Can we generated pre-signed url using Php?

Comment: I have a question on pre-signed url . Pre-signed url will expire in 3 minutes. Say I have video. User access video playing page, but not clicked play button. After 5 minutes(pre-signed url might be expired by that time) if user click play button, will the video play?

Comment: See AWS documentation for PHP SDK: [Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URL in PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-url.html).

Comment: You can specify the duration of validity for a pre-signed URL. So, if you set it to 3 minutes, then it will not work after 5 minutes. The URL is checked by S3 at the time that the request is made to S3. So, issue a longer validity period (it can be years!) or re-issue the URL so the user can access the data.